# How to access non container App data/Logs from an Azure-IoT-Edge Container App in gateway/Server?

Tags: azure-iot-edge

In  Azure-IoT-Edge, How to Access non container App data/Logs from an Azure-IoT-Edge Container App in gateway/Server and Push data to Azure IoT Hub cloud?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day it's the docker container running on a machine and in docker container you can run services that listen to the data that is posted on those services. Some solutions can be:-

1. A http server running on your edge module container and producers posting data to the RESTful api exposed by the container. Once data received, push it to IoT Hub using routes in edgeHub.
2. You can also run a consumer on docker container that listens to a message broker and passes that data to IoT hub using edgeHub routes.